# how to create dict with keys from list and static values in jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, templates, jinja2

i have list

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

and another

```
b = ['a','b']
```

how to make a dict like this:

```
{
1: ['a','b'],
2: ['a','b'],
3: ['a','b']
}
```

expression like

```
dict(a,map(b)) is not working
```

Comment: Doing this in the first place is probably not the best idea - it's a pattern that works a lot better in "implicit copies everywhere" languages like C++. While you can make copies manually in Python, copy functionality in Python isn't anywhere near as reliable or as integrated into the language.

Comment: `{item: b for item in a}`

Comment: (The copies here are the copies you'd have to make of `b`, because `{item: b for item in a}` like Alexander Lekontsev suggests would produce a dict where all values are references to the same list object.)

Answer (score 0):

Jinja templates have also for loops, you should try doing something similar to that:

```py
{% for nb in a %}
  {{ nb }}: {{ a[nb-1] }}
{% endfor %}
```